# Is integer multicommodity flow problem is NP-hard?

Tags: time-complexity, np-complete, np-hard, integer-programming

As Wikipedia states the time complexity of Integer Linear programming(ILP) is NP-hard, so this means integer multicommodity flow problem is also NP-hard?

Answer (score 2):

Integer multi-commodity flow is indeed NP-complete, as stated in the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-commodity_flow_problem#Solutions) ([link to the reference paper](https://doi.org/10.1137%2F0205048)).

However, your reasoning is incorrect. If ILP is NP-complete and some problem X reduces to ILP, it does not mean that X is NP-complete. In order to show NP-completeness of X via ILP (or any other NP-complete problem) you need to provide the reduction in the opposite direction — from ILP to X: that is, given an arbitrary ILP instance, convert it to a network such that finding the multi-commodity flow in that network will give the solution to the original ILP instance.

NB. Just to clarify: you can replace *NP-complete* with *NP-hard* in the above explanation. NP-completeness means both being NP-hard and belonging to NP, and showing the latter is trivial for mentioned problems.